# Server side Firebase listeners with load balancing

Tags: firebase, load-balancing, amazon-elb

If i want to use Firebase on the server side, in place of REST routes using express and node.js, how would I go about dealing with scaling and load balancing? So for example, if I have an express app that uses Firebase on the server side, will every single server that spins up contain these listeners and react to them? Is there a scale-able solution to using Firebase on the server-side with elastic load balancing in mind?

Comment: If you want each server to respond to the same Firebase events, then **yes** you will have to set up listeners from each server. Given that Firebase regularly handles a million concurrent connections or more, I wouldn't worry about **their** side of the scalability because of your connections.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to figure out the opposite. How to make sure each server that is up is not responding to the events. So if i'm a user, I'm currently using server-a, i don't want server b,c,and d to react to my events...

Comment: There is probably an interesting question lurking in here. But the description you've given so far is too broad to be able to provide an authoritative answer. Feel free to edit it and expand on the scenario you have in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your question is too broad in its current form, but will give you at least a few (equally broad) options.

There are probably dozens of solutions possible, but most of them will be variations on these two broad scenarios: centralized vs decentralized.

You can use a **centralized authority**, which assigns each task to one of the worker nodes. This is normally what a load balancer does, so you might want to search for load balancing algorithms.

Alternatively you can have each node simply try to **claim the work**. The nodes should then use a `transaction` to update the "work queue", so that only one node ends up doing the work.

Related: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-queue